# I just need to redirect vote to details,every things work fine except the last line of vote

Tags: django, redirect, args

**strong text**[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1OAJ.jpg*emphasized text*

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Please copy *code fragments* in the question, not *images*. Explain the problem: what is not working, what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and use your url parameter instead of pk :

```
reverse('details', kwargs={'pk': chose_id})
```